# how does get_term_by know which term to return when the same term appears twice in a hierarchical taxonomy?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, terms

This is from the codex.

```
<?php get_term_by( $field, $value, $taxonomy, $output, $filter ) ?>
```

Suppose I have a taxonomy system as follows;

taxonomy: "healthy foods"
and it's a hierarchical taxonomy and your hierarchy goes exactly like this;

```
healthy foods
    fruits
        red ones
        green ones
    veggies
        red ones
        green ones
```

and you use the `get_term_by` function as follows;

get_term_by("name","red ones","healthy foods")

Do you get the veggies or the fruits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`get_term_by()` just returns the first matching term, 'first' meaning some internal order in MySQL.

If having multiple terms with the same name matters in your case, don't rely on `get_term_by()` alone.

Comment: Thanks Scribu. I'm glad you are hanging out here. Tell me please, if this site, or the stackoverflow site or the wp-hackers list is a better place to ask wordpress questions... I got myself into a huge wordpress project and I just don't have the proper shoes for it yet. So, I'm gonna need lots of help.

Comment: @AverageJoe this is absolutely the community for WordPress questions, I constantly am on here learning new things just from questions I read through. You'll figure it out, I'm sure.

Answer (score 0):

You get the first one WP comes to in the database query. 
To get both terms that match use:

`get_terms( [
   'taxonomy'=>'healthy foods', 
   'name'=>'red ones', 
   'hide_empty' => 0 ] )`

See: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/